# Wireshark - How to filter on JSON content not sent over HTTP

Tags: wireshark

I have a windows service that uses winsock communicating to another windows service that uses winsock. We are talking over TCP/IP using JSON.

I am trying to prove that my service is behaving properly and that the service it communicates to is not sending the expected data.

I set up wireshark to capture on the Ethernet card I am using on my local machine and filter on ip.addr ==  and I can see the traffic.

I am expecting messages that contain "Message One" and I can see them, thousands of them.
While I am receiving all those, I expect a few messages that contain "Message Two"

How do I set up the filter to prove that I am not receiving the "Message Two" messages?

I Googled a little bit and someone said use data-text-lines contains "Message Two", but that doesn't work. I can verify it doesn't work by looking at the messages that contain "Message One" and then filtering data-text-line contains "Message One" and they all disappear when they shouldn't. I have a feeling that is for http only.

What do I use for a filter?

---

EDIT - To reply to v.j's response and have the ability to upload an img:

I do not see the "Expression" button. Here are some screenshots.

[image: Analyze menu]
[image: Display Filters...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark supports filter for JSON as well. Go to Analyze->Display Filter and then click on Expression button to configure different Filter String like -> JSON object, JSON Array etc. along with relation like "contains" or "is present"

[image]

This should help to set up JSON related filters.

EDIT: Attaching screenshot on how to access expression via button
[image]

EDIT2: Expression can be accessed in Wireshark Version 2.4.0 as shown below
[image]

Comment: @Christopher - I'm using Wireshark Version 1.12.8 wherein this feature is available. Can you check if you have older version?

Comment: My version is v2.2.7-0-g1861a96

Comment: @Christopher - Thanks for version details. I downloaded latest version 2.4.0 and Expression is available as per EDIT2 of my post. Hope this helps in JSON filtering.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
 http.content_type == "application/json"
```